# Magento 2 meta title empty on home page

Tags: magento2, home-page, meta-title

I fill meta title for design settings and for seo settings in homepage cms, and still on homepage have empty meta title, for each other page works great.

Where I should find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `page_content_heading` hasn't been removed in your layout updates. CMS pages are passed through the helper method `\Magento\Cms\Helper\Page::prepareResultPage` which looks for that block. If the block is included it will go through the usual `_prepareLayout` process which contains the method which sets your meta title from the page data.